# Through the Google Maps API it is possible to know the provinces, regions that fall within an area that is obtained with a radius from a given point?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

if through the Google Maps API it is possible to know the provinces, regions and nations that fall within an area that is obtained with a radius of x km from a given point?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. The Google Maps API does not provide the ability to dump all features within a particular geographic area and only allows searching for a particular type of place.

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search for more information.